# Different result when executing bpy.ops.uv.smart_project versus doing manually in 3D View

Tags: python, scripting, uv, texture-baking, project

I don't know whether I'm doing any mistake, but this is how my UVs are when I do *Smart UV Project* inside Blender editor manually.

[image]

But as far I switched to scripting:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin=0.06)
```

[image]

The result in scripting is very tiny and spacing is not accurate.
Kindly guide me if I am doing any mistake in my script.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your angle is incorrect. You have to pass your angle as radians, not degrees.

```
import bpy
import math as m

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=m.radians(66), island_margin=0.06)
```

Comment: Ohh, I had this doubt before but on internet so many examples people were using 66 as degrees. By the way thanks for quick response

Comment: you're welcome!