# How to UV unwrap list of objects using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, error

I want to UV Unwrap with `Smart UV Project` but don't want to use `bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()`.

In Blender 3.6 LTS, I tried with `context.temp_override()` but got this error:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


override = context.copy()
override['mode'] = 'EDIT_MESH'
override['selected_objects'] = [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']] # will replace with another list of objects

with context.temp_override(**override):
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=1.15192, margin_method='SCALED', island_margin=0, area_weight=0, correct_aspect=True, scale_to_bounds=False)
```

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: It's strange. The script worked fine for me with the same version of Blender. You are in Edit Mode?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296981/different-result-when-executing-bpy-ops-uv-smart-project-versus-doing-manually-i/296985#296985

Comment: btw usage of `override=context.copy()` i think is deprecated. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: @tetii Yes it works in `Edit` mode, but I want it in `Object` mode. I also tried using `override['mode'] = 'EDIT_MESH'`

Comment: don't use `override = context.copy()` that is deprecated. use `override = {}`. that will work in edit mode. bmesh doesnt have a direct uv unwrap method. I don't think you can avoid going into Edit mode.

Comment: yes, but `override = context.copy()` get a copy of the context as `dict`. So I don't have to fill the `dict` if I use `override = {}`.

Comment: yeah but thats causing error because it is deprecated since version 3.2. deprecated means that the code no longer supports this. now the proper way is not to pass a context copy of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the wrong context. Your context is in *Object Mode* but you need to be in *Edit Mode*. Here is the working script:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

selected_objects = [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']]

for obj in selected_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)

area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

if len(areas) <= 0:
    raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

with bpy.context.temp_override(
    window=bpy.context.window,
    area=areas[0],
    regions=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
    screen=bpy.context.window.screen
):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=1.15192, margin_method='SCALED', island_margin=0, area_weight=0, correct_aspect=True, scale_to_bounds=False)
```

**EDIT**: Oh we don't even need to do any context overrides still works:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

selected_objects = [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']]

for obj in selected_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=1.15192, margin_method='SCALED', island_margin=0, area_weight=0, correct_aspect=True, scale_to_bounds=False)
```

Comment: I don't want to use `bpy.ops`, any better Python way? I also tried using `override['mode'] = 'EDIT_MESH'`

Comment: Is it possible to do with `bmesh`?